# Multiplying conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, factoring

I have a question about merging conditional probabilities and pointers to sources to understand the terms/concepts associated with this question.

Is the following true?

p(a|b)*p(b|c) = p(a|c) ?

I've seen a similar equation before and I was wondering if this is correct and what the term for this is (as well as more background)?

Comment: Consider the case where $a$ and $b$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Alternatively, consider the case in which all three events are pairwise independent.